# 2006, 'SSL connection error: unknown error number'

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, anaconda

I'm using `Anaconda` and `python3.7` and I'm trying to connect to a remote database using the following code:

```
import MySQLdb
myDB = MySQLdb.connect(host="xxxxx", port=3306, user="xxx",password="xxxx",db="xxxx")
```

but I get the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\zanto\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 208, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)

OperationalError: (2006, 'SSL connection error: unknown error number')
```

I tried 2 users in mysql one using `%` and one using `localhost` but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem of `mySQLdb` library.

I installed `pymysql` library through `anaconda` and now it's working!

My new code is:

```
import pymysql.cursors
connection = pymysql.connect(host='xxxx',port=3306,user="xxxx",password="xxxx",db="xxxx", cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql="SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field = 'value'"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        #print (results) #if you remove the comment you will get the query result as a dictionary
        for record in results:
            record_line = " ".join('{0}{1}'.format(field,value) for field,value in record.items())
            print(record_line)

finally:
    connection.close()
```

**More info**: A cursor allows Python code to execute MySQL command in a database session. A cursor is created by the connection.cursor() method: they are bound to the connection for the entire lifetime and all the commands are executed in the context of the 
database session wrapped by the connection.

The cursor.execute() method runs a query in MySQL database. The cursor.fetchall() method returns the results of a query in list form that contains the records as dictionaries.